# PHP PDO bindParam and PDOBindArray with MySQL IN condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am converting an old MySQL query to use PHP PDO and need some insight on how to go about it.
Here's the example of the old code.

```
$deleted = false;

// get the image(s)
$sql = "SELECT cat_image 
        FROM category
        WHERE cat_id ";

if (is_array($catId)) 
{
    $sql .= " IN (" . implode(',', $catId) . ")";
} 
else 
{
    $sql .= " = $catId";
}   

$result = dbQuery($sql);

if (dbNumRows($result)) 
{
    while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) 
    {
        // delete the image file
        $deleted = @unlink(CATEGORY_IMAGE_DIR . $row['cat_image']);
    }   
}

return $deleted;
```

And here is my PDO example that I am trying to create to do the same job.
Note: in both examples $catId value could be an array or an (int) value.
How do I go about creating the sql statement and handing of the bindParam and PDOBindArray?

```
$deleted = false;

// get the image(s)
$sql = "SELECT cat_image 
        FROM category
        WHERE cat_id ";

if (is_array($catId)) 
{
    $sql .= " IN (" . implode(',', $catId) . ")";
} 
else 
{
    $sql .= " = $catId";
}   

$_stmt = $this->_dbConn->prepare($sql);
$_stmt->bindParam(":catId", $catId, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$_stmt->execute();

$res = $_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

if (count($res)) {
    while ($row = each($res)) {

        // delete the image file
        $deleted = @unlink(CATEGORY_IMAGE_DIR . $row['cat_image']);
    }   
}

return $deleted;
```

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

Comment: You might make life easier for yourself if `$catId` was always an array. If there's a single value, just have one entry in the array (`...WHERE cat_id IN (5)...` is perfectly valid SQL equivalent to `...WHERE cat_id = 5...`.)

Comment: btw, your loop approach is outdated as well. with PDO you can do `foreach ($stmt as $row) {` right after execute, without fetchAll, count, while and each